# What is the lower bound for the sum of the independence numbers of a graph and its complement?

Tags: graph-theory, extremal-graph-theory

The **independence number** $\alpha(G)$ of a graph $G$ is the cardinality of the largest independent vertex set.

My question is as stated in the title. We can observe from a path with $n$ vertices that its independence number is $\lceil \frac{n}{2} \rceil $ and its complement has independence number 2. So $\alpha(G)+\alpha(\overline G)=\lceil \frac{n}{2} \rceil +2$.

Are there graphs whose $\alpha(G)+\alpha(\overline G)$  is smaller than $\lceil \frac{|V(G)|}{2} \rceil +2$? Note that their upper bound is $|V(G)|+1$; and it can be seen in the link  [minimum independence number of graph G and the maximum independence number of G's complement?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2540610/whats-the-relation-between-the-minimum-independence-number-of-graph-g-and-the-m).

---

Note that the clique number of a graph is equal to the independence number of the complement graph.

Answer (score 1):

Let $n=k^2$ and consider the complete $k$-partite graph $K_{k,k,\dots,k}$, whose complement is the disjoint union of $k$ copies of $K_k$.

- Its independence number is $k$ since the clique number of its complement is obviously $k$.
- Its own clique number is also $k$ – taking one vertex from each part yields a clique, but a set of $k+1$ vertices will have two vertices from the same part by the pigeonhole principle; these vertices will not be adjacent.

Thus for this graph on $n$ vertices $\alpha(G)+\alpha(\overline G)=2\sqrt n$. This construction easily generalises to non-square $n$, so we can achieve sums of $\lceil2\sqrt n\rceil$.

Comment: Nice. Interestingly, will it reach a constant level?

Comment: @licheng $\sqrt n$ is definitely not constant, or bounded.

Comment: I know. I refer to, for geneal graphs, is there a tight lower bound for $\alpha(G)+\alpha(\overline{G})$?

Comment: @licheng According to the famous lower bound for Ramsey numbers, for $k\ge3$  we have $R(k,k)\gt2^{k/2}$, *i.e.*, if $n\le2^{k/2}$ there is a graph $G$ of order $n$ with $\alpha(G)\lt k$ and $\omega(G)=\alpha(\overline{G})\lt k$.